# Change a string array into an array of strings

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string that contains an array:

```
"[one, two, three]"
```

I'd like to change it into an array of strings, like this:

```
["one", "two", "three"]
```

Any help would greatly appreciated!

Update:
Thank you all for your help, you can see the results of this here:
http://kittykatattack.github.io/storymaker/

Comment: You have a string that contains an array? Wtf, I thought a string contains a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite as pretty as wared's answer...

```
("[one, two, three]").slice(1,-1).split(",");

// taking into account whitespace
("[one, two, three]").slice(1,-1).replace(/\s/g, "").split(/,/)

// or as @CasimiretHippolyte pointed out...
console.log(("[one, two, three]").slice(1,-1).split(/\s*,\s*/));
```

Comment: +1 this avoid the problem of how elements look like. However you can have leading spaces.

Comment: Yep, you are right... Should probably trim whitespace too.

Comment: It's easy since split supports regexes. with `split(/\s*,\s*/)`

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
'[one, two, three]'.match(/\w+/g);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the the leading and trailing brackets, then split on the commas. Something like this should do it:

```
'[one, two, three]'.replace(/^\[|\]$/g, '').split(', ');
```

Hope that helps. Cheers!

Comment: +1 - Probably the best answer. However, the split as `split(/\s*,\s*/)` could be more affective.